# Get production data for the last 2 days

Tags: php, sql, oracle

I have a question regarding fetching the fabrication data from two days ago. my code works but i think its inefficient with my implementation. What i have is this,

```
// YESTERDAYS FABRICATION
            $yesterdaySql = "SELECT SUM(CURRENT_WEIGHT) AS TOTALYESTERDAYWEIGHT FROM FABRICATION_HIST 
                                WHERE TO_CHAR (FAB_ENTRY_DATE,'MM/DD/YYYY') = TO_CHAR(SYSDATE - 1, 'MM/DD/YYYY') 
                                AND PROJECT_NAME = :projName";
            $yesterdayParse = oci_parse($conn, $yesterdaySql);
            oci_bind_by_name($yesterdayParse, ":projName", $_SESSION['cd-dropdown']);            
            oci_define_by_name($yesterdayParse, "TOTALYESTERDAYWEIGHT", $sumWeightYesterday);
            oci_execute($yesterdayParse);

            // TWO DAYS AGO FABRICATION
            $twoDaysSql = "SELECT SUM(CURRENT_WEIGHT) AS TOTALTWODAYSAGOWEIGHT FROM FABRICATION_HIST 
                                WHERE TO_CHAR (FAB_ENTRY_DATE,'MM/DD/YYYY') = TO_CHAR(SYSDATE - 2, 'MM/DD/YYYY') 
                                AND PROJECT_NAME = :projName";
            $twoDaysParse = oci_parse($conn, $twoDaysSql);
            oci_bind_by_name($twoDaysParse, ":projName", $_SESSION['cd-dropdown']);            
            oci_define_by_name($twoDaysParse, "TOTALTWODAYSAGOWEIGHT", $sumWeightTwoDays);
            oci_execute($twoDaysParse);
```

I know this is very inefficient. anybody can suggest me so that i can fetch two days query in a single query?

thanks in advance

Comment: Pass in the time limits from PHP as query parameter and then just compare `FAB_ENTRY_DATE` to those. You also need only one parametrised query then.

Comment: If there's a performance issue, it will be most probably in the DB itself. A single query instead of two won't be of much effect here (in my opinion). You better ask for a tuning of the DB query itself. And for that, I recommend that you post here the execution plan of the query.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here you are ...

```
SELECT
    SUM(CASE WHEN TRUNC(FAB_ENTRY_DATE) = TRUNC(SYSDATE) - 1 THEN CURRENT_WEIGHT END) AS TOTALYESTERDAYWEIGHT,
    SUM(CASE WHEN TRUNC(FAB_ENTRY_DATE) = TRUNC(SYSDATE) - 2 THEN CURRENT_WEIGHT END) AS TOTALTWODAYSAGOWEIGHT
FROM FABRICATION_HIST 
WHERE FAB_ENTRY_DATE >= TRUNC(SYSDATE) - 2
    AND FAB_ENTRY_DATE < TRUNC(SYSDATE)
    AND PROJECT_NAME = :projName
;
```

... and it's even well-indexable by:

```
create index i_fabrication_hist_something
on t_fabrication_hist (project_name, fab_entry_date)
compress 1
compute statistics
;
```

Comment: thanks @nop77svk. And how to skip sunday if today or tomorrow is monday ?